# How to pass https_connection_factory in boto3 resource connection?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

In the [boto3 document](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html), it shows an example of how to migrate the connection from boto 2.x to boto3

```
# Boto 2.x
import boto
s3_connection = boto.connect_s3()

# Boto 3
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

However, [in boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.connection.S3Connection), it is possible to pass a parameter `https_connection_factory`. What is the equivalent in boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a direct equivalent. When creating a [client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client) or [resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource), you can make some very broad choices about SSL (`use_ssl`, `verify`). Both those can also take a [`botocore.config.Config`](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/config.html) object which can let you control timeouts and http pooling behavior among other options.

However, if you want full control of the ssl context, there doesn't appear to be any official support. Internally, boto is using a [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session) to do all its work. You can see where the session is setup [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/c632931a6cc5eab4113c976d430bcb9c059f829f/botocore/endpoint.py#L79). If you're okay with digging into botocore's internal implementation, you could reach into your resources/clients to mount a new custom Adapter for `https://` paths as described in the [requests user guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version). The path to the http session object is `<client>._endpoint.http_session` or `<resource>.meta.client._endpoint.http_session`.